# ¿como hacer para que un div ocupe el alto total de una imagen y sea responsive?

Tags: css

tengo un div que contiene una imagen, cuando disminuyo el tamaño  de la ventana se crea un borde top y bottom en el contenedor, quisiera ue el  alto tambien se modificara: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo del contenedor es este:

```
        .section__slider{
             border: 3px solid black;
             max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.1fr 3fr 0.1fr 0.5fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        }
```

el cdigo de las imagenes es este:

```
    .sliderImg{
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         object-fit: cover;
        /* hace que la imagen se vea en x la mitad y en y 0 o la parte 
        superior */
         /* object-position: 50% 0%; */
    }
```

---

```
<section class="section__slider">
    <a href="#" class="previos">&laquo;</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">&raquo;</a>
                       <a class="slider-slide active" href="">
                            <img class="sliderImg" src="assets/images/purplecat.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a class="slider-slide" href="">
                            <img class="sliderImg" src="assets/images/slider_cita.png" alt="ddfd">

                        </a>
                        <a class="slider-slide" href="">
                            <img class="sliderImg" src="assets/images/AdoptaPoster.png" alt="rrrrr">

                        </a>

</section>
```

Comment: Podes pegar el fragmento del HTML? Igual creo que el `position: absolute` podria afectar.